# Can't use the java.net.http module/package in an android studio project

Tags: java, android, java-http-client

I'm using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 for a school project and I need to use an API.
In order to use the API I need to send an HTTP request to a certain URL.
I read about java 11's `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest` from the package `java.net.http` and tried to use it but the android studio can't seem to find this package and puts the error:

`error: package java.net.http does not exist  import java.net.http.HttpClient;`

I tried checking why it may show this error and I checked the gradle jdk version but it shows that it is version 11.

[image: android studio gradle version]

Comment: Despite sharing a huge chunk of the APIs, Android *is not* Java. So while "the basics" are very similar, newer stuff usually takes a while to arrive at Android and/or won't be supported ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a long history of not having traditional Java packages outside of the core collections and objects, let alone any Java features beyond Java 7 (java.time as one example).

Android has its own HTTP client library, as documented in the [Connectivity guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity), or you can opt for other libraries like Retrofit, for example.